# Cleaning up after a python script has been run locally vs from Django

Tags: python, django, garbage-collection, persistence

EDIT: When I say "global variables" in the post, I'm referring to the mtcbody script; the django code doesn't make use of global variables.

I have a rather cryptic problem; I have a python script that takes in an XML file, parses it and returns some sort of result. This script has some global variables which it uses to do its job. when I run this script locally, from eclipse for example, these global variables and everything else is automatically destroyed at the end and a new run uses new resources (as expected).

However, when I run this script from a Django view, I expect the same behaviour but instead, this script persists the global variables and adds to them every time a request is made.

Here's an example of running it locally from eclipse:

```
import mtcbody

def doShit():
    context = {}
    result = mtcbody.getData()

    # the variable result['tvas_after'] is one of the global variables in the mtcbody script
    print 'TVAs after: ' + str(result['tvas_after'])

    return context

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doShit()
```

And the result after first run:

```
TVAs after: {'1': <mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7f28011aac20>}
```

The result after second run:

```
TVAs after: {'1': <mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7f94bbb96c20>}
```

The result after third run:

```
TVAs after: {'1': <mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7f9509f49c20>}
```

As you can see, the dictionary that holds TVA instances is repopulated from scratch during each run; now compare that with the behaviour I get when running the same script from a django view:

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    result = mtcbody.getData()

    print 'TVAs after: ' + str(result['tvas_after'])

    return render(request, 'dashboardbase/table.html', context)
```

Result after first refresh (request)

```
TVAs after: {'1': <multitvaconfig.mtc.mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7ff0850fb488>}
```

Result after second refresh (request)

```
TVAs after: {'1': <multitvaconfig.mtc.mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7ff0850fb488>, '2': <multitvaconfig.mtc.mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7ff066e4afc8>}
```

Result after third refresh (request)

```
TVAs after: {'1': <multitvaconfig.mtc.mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7ff0850fb488>, '3': <multitvaconfig.mtc.mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7ff0a1fa4ea8>, '2': <multitvaconfig.mtc.mtcbody.TVA instance at 0x7ff066e4afc8>}
```

As you can see, the variables in the script are being retained between calls to Django view. Can someone please explain this behaviour and if possible how to avoid it and make it behave as if run locally.

Thank you

Comment: Does `mtcbody` use global variables inside it?

Comment: Yes, when I say "global variables" in my post, I'm referring to the mtcbody script. My Django code doesn't use any global variables.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you find this behaviour hard to explain. A script is run once and then quits, but a server application is persistent, therefore it should not be surprising that global data is persistent within that application.

The solution should be obvious: don't use global variables. They are rarely helpful, except in the odd cases when you *do* actually want data to persist between calls. Especially in a server environment, where different users can be requesting a resource at different times, global variables are dangerous. In your case, without seeing the relevant functions within `mtcbody` it's hard to advise, but it seems like you should pass around the data within that module, perhaps via a class.

Comment: I realised my naivety as soon as I posted the question, nonetheless your answer was helpful. The mtcbody script is long (5000~ lines) and was written by someone else a while ago as a standalone local program and my task is to provide it's functionality through web. mtcbody relies a LOT on global variables and there's no getting away from it short of a complete refactor.